# Display UIView On a Mac

Tags: ios, macos, uiview, desktop, nsview

First off all I don't have much experience in Mac Desktop Programming. I only worked on iOS apps.

Now I would like to make a desktop application that helps me develop iOS apps. To do that I would need to display a UIView (loaded from a xib) on the desktop, similar to how interface builder works.

As far as I know desktop applications use `NSView`. Is there any way to display a UIView inside a `NSView`?

EDIT: Is there any way to convert a `UIView` to a `NSView`?

EDIT2: Is there any way to write plugins/extensions for Interface Builder?

EDIT3: I'm trying to build an application that would make the development of certain iOS apps(presentation apps) easier. For example an app that displays multiple views in a scrollview, each view having some graphical elements that are animated and some buttons that  make a popup appear. This kind of apps are easy to develop but tedious. I would like to make a tool that would help me build such apps faster.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't write an iOS app and run it on the device (or the simulator)?

Comment: Well that would be a solution. But the application would be easier to use with a mouse / keyboard / big screen.

Comment: For that mater, why can't you just use Interface Builder? Perhaps if you explain what you're trying to do, we can suggest some alternatives/workarounds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your description of the app you're trying to build, I might suggest that you write XIB XML directly, rather than trying to manipulate `UIViews` on OS X. You might use the emulator to lay out the controls, then generate a serialized representation of the hierarchy (position, etc.) on the device. You could generate XIB XML from that serialization, either on the device or on your desktop after pulling the serialized form back from the emulator.

Answer (score 7):

UIKit (the iOS UI framework, including `UIView`) does not run on OS X (the Mac desktop OS). There have been several efforts to create a 3rd party UIKit port to OS X. Of these, [Chameleon](http://chameleonproject.org/) may be the most advanced. It still implements only about 60% of UIKit (according to the project page), but has been used in shipping applications. It was developed by the makers of Twitterific to port their iOS app to OS X, and I believe is still the foundation of that product on the desktop.

*Converting `UIView` to `NSView`*

There is no way to "convert" a `UIView` to an `NSView`. Since you can't load UIKit on OS X (or AppKit on iOS), there's no way to instantiate a `UIView` and then walk its view hierarchy to instantiate an equivalent `NSView`. Of course, since the semantics of `UIView` are different from `NSView`, it's unclear whether there could be a deterministic mapping. `NSView` hierarchies are view-based, whereas `UIView` hierarchies make much more pervasive use of CoreAnimation layers. `NSView` has its roots in the NeXT AppKit framework. There are a number areas where AppKit is showing its age. UIKit is a fresh start, "fixing" many of these legacy issues in AppKit (of course, introducing it's own future "legacy" issues).

It *may* be possible to parse the XIB, instantiating roughly equivalent `NSViews` where there is a meaningful mapping from `UIView` to `NSView`. Custom `UIViews` will be completely off the table in this scheme, and there won't be any way to (easily) match look and feel without writing custom `NSViews` for each `UIView` (ala the Chameleon project).

*IB plugins*

Interface Builder 3 did suppert a plugin architecture. With Xcode 4, Interface Builder no longer supports third-party plugins. Sorry.

**Edit**

Unfortunately, I don't believe Chameleon can load views from XIBs, so you may have to contribute to the project if you want to load XIB views instead of instantiating them in code... as Ashley points out, you may be diving into a *very* deep rabbit hole.

Answer (score 3):

NO. UIView only work on iPhone. Use NSView on mac.

Comment: Is there some way to write a plugin for Interface Builder, maybe?

Comment: Xcode 4 did away with plugins. Why would you think they would be a solution anyway? UIView's won't run natively on the desktop, which is why there is a simulator for iOS development.

Comment: Well the application I'm thinking about would be used to develop iOS applications. For example adding animations to objects using a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. One is part of the Cocoa (Mac) framework, the other is in CocoaTouch (iOS).

Not sure what you mean by *convert a UIView to a NSView*

What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps there are other ways to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out http://chameleonproject.org/